# Select hibernate criteria com entidade nao mapeada

Tags: banco-de-dados, hibernate, java, criteria

tem como eu fazer um select, usando o criteria e trazer uma entidade não mapeada, seriam vários joins, e as vezes trazer determinados campos e outros não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criteria você não pode fazer sem uma entidade, mas você pode usar o Native Query para executar queries.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select s.stock_code from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode").setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
List result = query.list();
```

Você pode ver mais em: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/

Comment: Com criteria você consegue trás classes não mapeadas, procure na documentação do hibernate 5.2 que usa o criteriabuilder do entitymanager que lá mostra como fazer.